# Switch case displays only default (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, date, switch-statement, typeerror

I'm trying to make a program where you input your Birthday, and it tells you whether today is your birthday, your birth-month, or if you have to wait a while until your birthday. Here it is:

```
  function isB_Day (month, day) {
   var m = Date.getMonth(); 
   var d = Date.getDate(); 

    switch (month) {
    case month === m: 
    if(day === d){
        alert('Happy Birthday To You!');
    } else {
        alert('Almost your B-Day dude!');
    };
        break;
      default: alert('You B-day won\'t be for a little while, bud. Hang     in there!');
  };

 };
```

But when I put:

```
    isB_Day(0, 27);
```

(Because its the 27th of January)
It gives me an error saying:

```
    VM332:2 Uncaught TypeError: Date.getMonth is not a function
    at isB_Day (<anonymous>:2:16)
    at <anonymous>:20:1
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Description

You simply need to initialize a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object, then call the functions [`getMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) and [`getDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) on the object.

Next, your switch statement is slightly wrong.  You are using the `case (month === m):` like an `if` statement.  However, a switch statement is basically like stating that if things match the switch parameter.

```
// this will check the string 'justin' against any case statement.
switch('justin') {
  case 'test':
    break;
}

// the same if statement would be
if ('justin' == 'test') {
}
```

Switch statements are mainly useful if you are checking on value against multiple possibilities and instead would have to have multiple `if`, `else if`, `else` statements.

```js
function isB_Day(month, day) {
  // initialize a Date object
  var now = new Date();
  // call getMonth on the object
  var m = now.getMonth();
  // call getDate on the object
  var d = now.getDate();

  // you are passing month into the switch
  switch (month) {
    // this checks the switch month against the case m
    case m:
      if (day === d) {
        console.log('Happy Birthday To You!');
      } else if (d > day) {
        console.log('Your birthday already happened this month');
      } else {
        console.log('Almost your B-Day dude!');
      }
      break;
    default:
      console.log("You B-day won't be for a little while, bud. Hang in there!");
      break;
  }
}

isB_Day(0, 27); 
isB_Day(0, 28);
isB_Day(1, 28);
```

---

### Quick Example of Why it didn't work

```js
// shows that Date is a native function
console.log(Date);
console.log(Date());

// Date is a function without calling the function it doesn't have the getMonth function
console.log(Date.getMonth());
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but now, even if it is my b-day, it says 'your b-day won't be for a while'?

Comment: @FOG.js fixed, adding to description now.

Comment: @FOG.js That is a confusing question, where are you using this code? in a normal Javascript site? normally, you should separate your JavaScript code into files from each page.  Then you can make other JavaScript Libraries that are used in multiple pages.

Comment: Oh!! I get it now! thank you so much! never mind my last question